# The problems in deducing the Laplace's equation of the minimal surface

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

The Minimal surface can usually be expressed as follows:

For region $\Omega \subset \mathbf{R}^2$,there is a space curve $L$ define on the boundary $\partial \Omega$ .Find a surface $S$ define on $\Omega$ so that $S$ is the minimum area surface whose boundary is $L$.
That is, in the function set $M_g=\{v\in C_1(\bar{\Omega})|,v|_{\partial\Omega}=g\}$, find $u\in M_g$ such that 
$$J(u)=\min_{v\in M_g}J(v),$$
where $$J(v)=\iint_{\Omega}\sqrt{1+|\nabla v|^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y.$$
When we consider the tiny change, the gradient $\nabla v$ is small,
$$\sqrt{1+|\nabla v|^2}\approx 1+\frac{1}{2}|\nabla v|^2.$$
so the minimal surface problem can be approximated as follows:

Find $u\in M_g$ so that
$$F(u)=\min_{v\in M_g}F(v),$$
where $$F(v)=\frac 12 \iint_{\Omega}|\nabla v|^2\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y.$$
To deduce the nessary conditions of $u\in M_g$,choose $\varphi \in
 C_0^1(\Omega),\varepsilon \in \mathbf{R}$,then $u+\varepsilon \varphi \in M_g$.Let $f(\varepsilon)=F(u+\varepsilon\varphi)$,and $f(\varepsilon)$ is a quadratic polynomial of $\varepsilon$.For $\varepsilon \in \mathbf{R},f(\varepsilon)\ge f(0)$ ,therefore, $f'(0)=0$, that is 
$$\iint_{\Omega} \nabla u\cdot \nabla \varphi\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=0.\qquad\qquad(1)$$
If $u\in C^2(\Omega)$,apply the Green theorem to $(1)$,we have
$$\iint_{\Omega}(-\triangle u)\varphi\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=0,\qquad\qquad (2)$$
since $\varphi$ is arbitrary ,$$\begin{cases}\triangle u=0,&\text{in } \Omega \\u|_{\partial \Omega=g}\end{cases}$$
I don't understand why should we choose $v\in C_0^1(\Omega)$?.Since $u+\varepsilon \varphi \in M_g$, $\varphi$ should equal $0$ on $\partial \Omega. $But what does $C_0^1(\Omega)$ mean? Differentiable function with compact support on $\Omega$? And how to deduce $(2)$ from $(1)$ by applying the Green theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the author, $C_0^1$ could mean either compactly supported inside $\Omega$ or (slightly weaker) vanishing on $\partial \Omega$ - the distinction is not very important here, since we're only doing a single integration by parts. Either way, we know $\varphi$ is differentiable and zero on the boundary, so applying the product rule we find $$\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi = \int_\Omega \mathrm{div}(\varphi \nabla u) - \int_\Omega \varphi \Delta u.$$

By the two-dimensional divergence theorem (or Stokes theorem, or Green's theorem - they're all the same, really) the first integral is  $$\int_\Omega \mathrm{div}(\varphi \nabla u) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \varphi \nabla u \cdot \hat n;$$ so since $\varphi$ vanishes on the boundary this term vanishes as desired.

Comment: Thanks!Your answer is understandable and helpful.I didn't notice that compact support implies vanishing on the boundary.